# Como remover palavras especificas com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Como posso remover valores específicos do titulo da pagina?

**Titulo**: STACKOVERFLOW

**REMOVER**: STACK

**RESULTADO**: OVERFLOW

Comment: Isto pode ajudar: https://www.regex101.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sabendo que podes acessar ao título da pagina via `document.title` então podes transformar essa string e voltar a definir o título com `document.title = novaString;`.

Isto vai ter implicações a nível de SEO que deves ter em conta... (isso é um assunto já abordado noutras perguntas).

Exemplo:

```
var titulo = document.title;
document.title = titulo.replace('STACK', ''); // vai mudar o titulo removendo "STACK"
```

Answer (score 2):

No caso do JavaScript você pode utilizar o método `substring`!
Com o método `substring` pegamos um pedaço da string, passamos a posição inicial seguida do número de caracteres que devem ser extraído.

Ex.:

```
var titulo = "Stackoverflow";
var resultado = titulo.substring(5, 15);

console.log(resultado);
```

Saída:

```
 overflow
```

Para pegar o title da página, utilize `document.title`

```
 var titulo = document.title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso você queria procurar por um valor específico em uma string, independente de seus indexes é possível usar o `suaString.indexOf('STACK')`, caso encontre algo tal método retornará o *index* do início da string (ex: 4), caso não encontre sua resposta será -1.

Exemplo:

```
var busca = "STACK";
var suaString = "STACKOVERFLOW";
var indexBusca = suaString.indexOf(busca);
// a variavel indexBusca irá armazenar o index do retorno, se for diferente de -1 é porque a string foi encontrada em 'suaString'
```